# configure mongodb spark connector with more than one host

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, configuration, connector

Is there a way to specify more than one MongoDB host in SparkConf?  The examples in the doc (https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/v1.1/configuration/) seems to suggest that no.

```
spark.mongodb.output.uri=mongodb://127.0.0.1/
spark.mongodb.output.database=test
spark.mongodb.output.collection=myCollection
```

Comment: AFAIK, No. Why do you need two connections?

Comment: I don't need two connections, I would like to provide a seed with more than one replica in case one of them is down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `spark.mongodb.input.uri` and `spark.mongodb.output.uri` accepts [MongoDB Connection URI format](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/).

The connection URI format should work across all MongoDB supported drivers, including the MongoDB Scala driver for Spark. For example, in order to connect to a replica set, you can specify:

```
mongodb://db1.example.net,db2.example.net:2500/?replicaSet=myReplica
```